# What the difference between albedo map and diffuse map?

Tags: texturing, shaders

From what I understand, the Albedo Map it's from PBR workflow, and Albedo is basically playing the role of Difuse Map on Lambert workflow.

But I think there must be some difference...
​

Comment: The Albedo map is the base color input that defines the diffuse color or reflectivity of the surface. You could read this https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/350/albedo-vs-diffuse